# Sort by filename with glob(..., GLOB_BRACE)

Tags: php, glob, braces

Let's say I have these files in the current folder:

```
a.txt
b.txtbis
c.txt
+ other files with other extensions
```

I want to list `.txt` and `.txtbis` files in a single list with PHP `glob`, and I want the result to be sorted by filename. Unfortunately:

- `glob("*.{txtbis,txt}", GLOB_BRACE)` gives `Array ( [0] => b.txtbis [1] => a.txt [2] => c.txt )`
- `glob("*.{txt,txtbis}", GLOB_BRACE)` gives `Array ( [0] => a.txt [1] => c.txt [2] => b.txtbis )`

None of them is sorted as it should.

**How to have a list sorted by filename when using braces in `glob`?**

Comment: Can't you `sort` after the call? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: How is `glob` related to sort?

Comment: @user3783243 `print_r(sort(glob("*.{txt,txtbis}", GLOB_BRACE)))` doesn't work, as `sort` returns a bool, so I have to: `$files=glob(...); sort($files); print_r($files)`. Is there a version of `sort` that gives the sorted array as the return value of the function?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes that's the same code as what I mentioned in my previous comment, but isn't there a way where `sort(...)` would have the sorted array as return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glob sorts the files by full path names (path + name + extension) alphabetically. If you only want to sort by (base)name, you can use usort:

```
$files = glob("*.{txtbis,txt}", GLOB_BRACE);

usort(
  $files, 
  function($a,$b){
    return basename($a) <=> basename($b);
  }
);

var_dump($files);
```